# MySQL paging large data based on a specific order

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, sql-order-by

Good Morning,

I have a table that contains couple million rows and I need to view the data ordered by the TimeStamp.

when I tried to do this

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC offset 0 LIMIT 200
```

the MySQL will order all the data and then will response with the 200 rows and this is a performance issue. because its not wise to order everything each time I want to scroll the page !

do you have any idea on how we could improve the performance ?

Comment: would you clarify why `offset 0` ?

Comment: Will records always be added to the table in chronological order? In that case, just add an autoincrement integer column `RowNumber` to your table, add an index to it, and use `WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 0 AND 200`.

Comment: @7alhashmi 0 is just an example of a variable it maybe anything ! its a paging system !

Comment: @Dan its not ordered and I can't edit the table !

Comment: If you can't edit the table because you don't have privileges, create your own table and import the data into it.  It's that important to be able to add an index on the column you're sorting by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you need to create an index based on the date field.  This allows the rows to be retrieved in order without having to sort the entire table every time a request is made.

Secondly, paging based on index gets slower the deeper you delve into the result set.  To illustrate:

- `ORDER BY indexedcolumn LIMIT 0, 200` is very fast because it only has to scan 200 rows of the index.
- `ORDER BY indexedcolumn LIMIT 200, 200` is relatively fast, but requires scanning 400 rows of the index.
- `ORDER BY indexedcolumn LIMIT 660000, 200` is very slow because it requires scanning 660,200 rows of the index.

  Note: even so, this may still be significantly faster than not having an index at all.

You can fix this in a few different ways.

1. Implement value-based paging, so you're paging based on the value of the last result on the previous page.  For example:

   `WHERE indexedcolumn>[lastval] ORDER BY indexedcolumn LIMIT 200` replacing [lastval] with the value of the last result of the current page.  The index allows random access to a particular value, and proceeding forward or backwards from that value.
2. Only allow users to view the first X rows (eg. 1000).  This is no good if the value they want is the 2529th value.
3. Think of some logical way of breaking up your large table, for example by the first letter, the year, etc so users never have to encounter the entire result set of millions of rows, instead they need to drill down into a specific subset first, which will be a smaller set and quicker to sort.

If you're combining a WHERE and an ORDER BY you'll need  to reflect this in the design of your index to enable MySQL to continue to benefit from the index for sorting.  For example if your query is:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE year='2012' ORDER BY date LIMIT 0, 200
```

Then your index will need to be on two columns (year, date) in that order.

If your query is:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE firstletter='P' ORDER BY date LIMIT 0, 200
```

Then your index will need to be on the two columns (firstletter, date) in that order.

The idea is that an index on multiple columns allows sorting by any column as long as you specified previous columns to be constants (single values) in a condition.  So an index on A, B, C, D and E allows sorting by C if you specify A and B to be constants in a WHERE condition.  A and B cannot be ranges.

Comment: it looks like this is the only solution but I can use it since I have no access to the database !! working with some clients are so hard if you don't have access or even real access to the database ! I even tried to create a dummy database and import data inside it but the solution DOES not work with the client and so we drop the feature ! ... as simple as possible :)

Comment: @thomasrutter : thank you for the explanation. a quick question : how can we use value-based paging when value is timestamp and we can have same timestamp values in  different rows --> in that case the LIMIT clause will create problem.

Comment: It would have to be done on a unique column or combination of columns.  If the order will never change (ie, a timestamp can't be modified) then consider using an autoincrement ID and sort on that column only.  Or you could sort on more than one column eg `ORDER by timestamp DESC, unique_ID DESC` so that in case of timestamp collision they are ordered by the ID.  You'd need to pass in both vars.